# Why my slideshow is scrolling down my screen?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, slideshow

My code is really messed up somehow. please, if anyone out there is a coding genius, ask for the code, and I will send you it right now. All I need is for my page to stop teleporting up like 500px every time I try to change one of the slides to a different one. Then, I can't even see the whole slide, so I have to scroll up again. super frustrating.

Here's the link to my website, I think the problem is in the css or something, so please use the inspect element. https://fc-sales.com/felipe1.html

In case you don't know how to inspect element, here is the code:

```css
.main{

    margin-top:150px;
}



/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////testpage1*/

.slide-container {
width:60%;
height:auto;


margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
}
.image-container {
  width:300%;
  height:auto;
  position: relative;
  transition:left 2s;
  -moz-transition:left 2s;
  -webkit-transition:left 2s;
  -o-transition: left 2s;

}
.slider-image {
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:33.333%;
height:auto;
}
.button-container {
  top: -30px;
  position:relative;
}
.slider-button {
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:white;
}


#slider-image-1:target ~ .image-container{
  left:0px;
}
#slider-image-2:target ~ .image-container{
  left:-100%;
}
#slider-image-3:target ~ .image-container{
  left:-200%;
}


.milkWhiteText{
  color:bisque;
  font-size:40px;
text-align:center;


 }

.milkWhiteText2{
  color:bisque;
  font-size:30px;



 }


#grad1 {
height:45vh;
background-color: red;
text-align:center;
font-size:8vh;
font-weight:bolder;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, aqua,chartreuse);
}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////home button on second test page*/

.btn {


    top: 0;

  float:left;
  background-color: rgb(80,80,80); /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}

/* Darker background on mouse-hover */

.btn:hover {
  background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}


.btn2 {

  background-color: rgb(80,80,80); /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 14px; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 12px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
  font-style:italic;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-hover */
.btn2:hover {
  background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}
.btn2:hover {
    cursor:grab;

}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Testpage2*/


.body2 {background-color:rgb(40,40,40);}


.slide-container2 {
width:60%;
height:auto;


margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
}



.image-container2 {
  width:500%;
  height:auto;
  position: relative;
  transition:left 2s;
  -moz-transition:left 2s;
  -webkit-transition:left 2s;
  -o-transition: left 2s;

}
.slider-image2 {
width:20%;
height: auto;
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.slider-button2 {
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:white;
}

.button-container2 {
  top: -40px;
  position:relative;
}

#slider-image-4:target ~ .image-container2{
  left:0px;
}

#slider-image-5:target ~ .image-container2{
  left:-100%;
}
#slider-image-6:target ~ .image-container2{
  left:-200%;
}
#slider-image-7:target ~ .image-container2{
  left:-300%;
}

#slider-image-8:target ~ .image-container2{
  left:-400%;
}



/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////for our Iframe video,Let's add a video wrapper*/

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;

}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=us>
    <head>
<meta charset=utf-8>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="description" content="Welcome to modern travel. The Sandpiper. It's made to be the feeling of absolute luxury. It's Beauty at its best, comfort at it's best, freedom on wheels, And it's the American Dream, at it's best."/>  

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>


    .navbar {
    z-index:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:rgb(40,40,40);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float:left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 padding:5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar2 {
    z-index:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:rgb(40,40,40);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

  width: 100%;
  margin-top:80px;
}

.navbar2 a {
  float:left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.main{

    margin-top:150px;
}



</style>

<title>

    Fc Sales | The Sandpiper

</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Rv,RV's,rv, rv's rvs, RVS, FC sales, fc sales, Fc sales, FC Sales, cars, Cars, trucks, Trucks, Sandpiper, sandpiper"/>



  </head>


<body class="body2">

<div class="navbar">

<a href="index.html"> <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i></button></a>
<a href="about us.html"> <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x"></i></button></a></div>
<br><br><div class="navbar2">
<a href="felipe1.html"><button class="btn2">About The Sandpiper</button></a>
<a href="felipe2.html"><button class="btn2">About The Bighorn</button></a>
</div>
<div class="main">

<p class="milkWhiteText" style="font-style:bolder; font-style:italic; font-size 29px;">buy this today! for the extremely low, once in a lifetime special, 0% interest, 0% down, cash on the barrel head, 0% OFF, special price of $1,000,000,000</p>
<div class ="slide-container">

          <span id="slider-image-1"></span>

                  <span id="slider-image-2"></span>

                        <span id="slider-image-3"></span>




                <div class = "image-container">

                  <img src="rvk1.jpg" class="slider-image" >

                    <img src="rvk2.jpg" class="slider-image" >

                  <img src="rvk3.jpg" class="slider-image" >

                </div>
              </div>
                  <div class=button-container style="text-align:center">

                          <a href=#slider-image-1 class="slider-button"></a>

                        <a href=#slider-image-2 class="slider-button"></a>

                      <a href=#slider-image-3 class="slider-button"></a>

                  </div>

<br><br><br><br><br>


 <div class="videoWrapper">

<iframe style="margin-left:19.65vw" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/APYcU16d37A?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>





<p class="milkWhiteText" style="font-size:40px;">

<em>
 The cleanest ride.
 The safest ride.<br>
 The prettiest ride.
 Luxury at it's best.
   </em> 


</p>


  <div class ="slide-container2">
    <span id="slider-image-4"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-5"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-6"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-7"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-8"></span>
      <div class = "image-container2">
          <img src="rvb1.jpg" class="slider-image2" >
          <img src="rvb2.jpg" class="slider-image2" >
          <img src="rvb3.jpg" class="slider-image2" >
          <img src="rvb4.jpg" class="slider-image2">
          <img src="rvb5.jpg" class="slider-image2" >

  </div>
<div class=button-container2>
<a href=#slider-image-4 class="slider-button2"></a>
<a href=#slider-image-5 class="slider-button2"></a>
<a href=#slider-image-6 class="slider-button2"></a>
<a href=#slider-image-7 class="slider-button2"></a>
<a href=#slider-image-8 class="slider-button2"></a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements with the `:target` pseudo-class, when clicked, result in their ID being added to the current URL, causing the element with that ID (for example `https://fc-sales.com/felipe1.html#slider-image-2`) being moved to the top of the window, just like when you click a local link. Watch the URL in your address bar after clicking one of these dots, you'll see it there.

I guess the animated movement of the image container should rather be done using Javascript instead, using an `onclick` event triggering an animation of the `left` parameter of the `.image-container` element.

Answer (score -1):

```
.image-container2 {
  height:849px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The container contains image with different heights, that's why It jumps, the page overall height changes, try to consider a frame for your slide show
or like my solution put a fixed height size for the container

2 methods can fix this,
setting the height as the lowest heights of the images
or using standard same size image

Also remember Always use `clearfix` when you float your child and don't specify height for the parent